# How do I iterate through pandas dataframe and calculate average?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

[Temperature Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uW5FQ.jpg)

I have a pandas dataframe which has the record maximum temperature and minimum temperature of every month of the years 1953 and 1954. Now I want to calculate average max and min temperature value of each year (eg. for each year summing up max temperatures of 12 months and dividing it by 12). How can I do that?

Comment: please provide the input and output dataframe as text and not image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you don't require Month column in output and want the mean of Max and Min Temperature by year.

**Solution**.

df.groupby('Year',as_index=False).mean().drop(columns='Month')

**Input**

```
    Year    Month   MaxTemperature  MinTemperature
0   1953    1       26.7            10.9
1   1954    2       29.2            9.9
2   1953    1       27.4            11.0
3   1954    2       28.0            11.2
4   1953    1       28.0            13.0
5   1954    2       25.4            9.4
6   1953    1       26.0            12.0
7   1954    2       29.1            10.5
```

**Output**

```
    Year    MaxTemperature  MinTemperature
0   1953      27.025          11.725
1   1954      27.925          10.250
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is the perfect answer.

Comment: Awesome, In that case you have an option to upvote the answer and accept it as expected answer by clicking the tick.

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
import numpy as np
df  = df.groupby('Year', as_index=False).agg({'MaxTemperature': np.mean, 'MinTemperature' : np.mean})
```